# How can I use a span tag in a PHP string or better way to create a tool tip?

Tags: php, string, tooltip

I have stories as a string in php for my mad libs and was wondering if there was an efficient way to add a tool tip?

```
 $story1 = ("<b><u>$noun2</u></b> an uh <b><u>$noun1</u></b> were driving through a wooded empty section of <b><u>$location1</u></b>. Lightning flashed, thunder roared, the sky went dark in the <b><u>$adjective1</u></b> downpour. 
<br /> 
    <br /> 'We'd better <b><u>$verb1</u></b>,'  said <b><u>$noun2</u></b>. 
<br />
     <br /> <b><u>$noun1</u></b> nodded his head in agreement. He stepped on the brake, and suddenly the car started to <b><u>$verb2</u></b> on the slick pavement. They plunged off the road and slid to a halt at the bottom of an incline.
```

Here is a sample of my code.

Comment: What's your problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Spans are the only way I can see to add a tool tip, which I cannot do in here.

Comment: Why can't you add a span? What's the issue?

Comment: Because I already used quotation marks right after the parentheses.